# ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795

Tags: python, tensorflow, importerror

**My Computer System :**

windows 7 64 bit
CPU intel Core 2 Duo 8400
python version 3.5.2rc1
tensorflow 1.11
I was trying to install tensorflow cpu version on windows7 , but always got error when import tensorflow.

I read the common_installation_problems , tried many solution I found on github, stackoverflow, etc. I install visual studio 2015, visual studio 2017, Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3 (64 bit), msvcp140.dll can find in both System32 and SysWow64 folder. But still can't import tensorflow.

Is there something I missed out?

#### Log Info

```
ImportError Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in 
57
---> 58 from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
59 from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import version

c:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in 
27 return _mod
---> 28 _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
29 del swig_import_helper

c:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper()
23 try:
---> 24 _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
25 finally:

c:\python\lib\imp.py in load_module(name, file, filename, details)
241 else:
--> 242 return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
243 elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:

c:\python\lib\imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file)
341 name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
--> 342 return _load(spec)
343

ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError Traceback (most recent call last)
in 
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

c:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_init_.py in 
20
21 # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order
---> 22 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow # pylint: disable=unused-import
23
24 try:

c:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python_init_.py in 
47 import numpy as np
48
---> 49 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
50
51 # Protocol buffers

c:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in 
72 for some common reasons and solutions. Include the entire stack trace
73 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 74 raise ImportError(msg)
75
76 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
File "c:\python\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
File "c:\python\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795
```

Comment: Are you using anaconda ?

Comment: i'm using pip3.

Comment: As mentioned in the answers this is caused by an old processor. which is not supporting AVX (see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18689)). One could try tensorflow builds without AVX like [here](https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel).

Answer (score 0):

please try to install the tensorflow version 1.5 or use **pip install --upgrade tensorflow**.

Comment: If you are using pip3 then please use the below command **pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow**

Comment: i found the problem is my processor. my processor is celeron so i only use tensorflow under v 1.5. thank's lot

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by installing `tensorflow` 1.5.0 as I downgraded it from `tensorflow` 1.13.1, which was my previous version.